# Unable to create kernel from SPIR-file in OpenCL

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, opencl, spir

I'm trying to compile a kernel written using Clang cl-std=clc++2021.
The clang compilation of the kernel runs fine:

`clang --target=spirv32 -Xclang -no-opaque-pointers  -cl-std=clc++2021 ERK.cpp -o ERK.spv`

My kernel code implements an explicit Runge-Kutta 4 integrator scheme:

```
void addVec(float* a, const float*b, const int Nx)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
    {
        a[i] += b[i];
    }
}

template <int Nstage_ERK, class f_ODE>
struct impl_ERK {

    constexpr static int NX = f_ODE::NX;
    impl_ERK(const float* _A, const float* _b, const float* _c): p_A(_A), p_b(_b), p_c(_c){}
    void solve(constant float* xk, float* xk_1, float t, float dt, const float* P) 
    {
        float K[Nstage_ERK * NX];
        float xk_stage[NX];
        for (int j = 0; j < NX; j++)
        {
            xk_stage[j] = xk[j];
        }
        f_ODE::solve(t, xk_stage, K, P);

        for (int i = 1; i < Nstage_ERK; i++) {
            float* k_i = &K[i * NX];
            float c_i = p_c[i];

            float ak_sum[NX];
            for (int j = 0; j < NX; j++) {
                ak_sum[j] = xk[j];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                ak_sum[j] += p_A[i * Nstage_ERK + j] * K[j * NX];
                xk_stage[j] = xk[j] + dt*ak_sum[j];
            }
            

            f_ODE::solve(t + c_i * dt, xk_stage, k_i,  P);

            for (int j = 0; j < NX; j++) {
                xk_1[j] += dt * p_b[i] * k_i[j];
            }
        }
    }
    private:
    const float* p_A; 
    const float* p_b;
    const float* p_c;
};


template <class f_ODE>
struct ERK4 : public impl_ERK<4,f_ODE> 
{
    ERK4(const float* _A, const float* _b, const float* _c) : impl_ERK<4,f_ODE>(_A, _b, _c){}
};


struct f_ODE_1
{
    constexpr static int NX = 3;
    constexpr static int NP = 3;
    static void solve(const float t, const float* xk, float* xdot, const float* P)
    {
        float alpha = P[0];
        float beta = P[1];
        float N_pop = P[2];

        xdot[0] = -beta*xk[0]*xk[1]/N_pop;
        xdot[1] = beta*xk[0]*xk[1]/N_pop - alpha*xk[1];
        xdot[2] = alpha*xk[1];
    }
};

// Example that uses find_min in a kernel with array of int4.
__kernel void compute(constant float* x0, global float* x1) 
{
    const float A[4*4] = {.0f,.0f,.0f,.0f,
    .5f,.0f,.0f,.0f,
    .0f,.5f,.0f,.0f,
    .0f,.0f,1.f,.0f};
    const float b[4] = {1.f/6, 1.f/3, 1.f/3, 1.f/6};
    const float c[4] = {.0f,.5f,.5f,1.f};
    const float dt = .5f;
    const float t = .0f;
    const float R0 = 1.2;
    const float alpha = .9;
    const float beta = R0*alpha;
    const float N_pop = 1e6;
    const float P[f_ODE_1::NP] = {alpha, beta, N_pop};
    float res[3];
    ERK4<f_ODE_1> integrator(A, b, c);
    integrator.solve(x0, res, t, dt, P);
}
```

Creating a program with `clCreateProgramWithIL(.)` and building it works fine, but I'm however not able to create any kernels using `clCreateKernelsInProgram(.)`

```
    clInstance.program = clCreateProgramWithIL(clInstance.context, (const void*) programBinary.data(), sizeof(char)*programBinary.length(), &err);

    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    std::string build_options = "-I " + cl_generator_dir + " -I " + ERK_Kernel_dir;
    /*Step 6: Build program. */
    int status = clBuildProgram(clInstance.program, 1, clInstance.device_ids.data(), build_options.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
    if (status == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
    {
        // Determine the size of the log
        size_t log_size;
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(clInstance.program, clInstance.device_ids[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);

        // Allocate memory for the log
        char *log = (char *)malloc(log_size);

        // Get the log
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(clInstance.program, clInstance.device_ids[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);

        // Print the log
        printf("%s\n", log);
    }



    float x0[3] = {1.0,2.0,3.0};
    float x_res[3] = {-10,-10,-10};

    size_t inputBufferSize = sizeof(float)*3;
    size_t outputBufferSize = sizeof(float)*3;

    cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(clInstance.context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, inputBufferSize, NULL, &err);
    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(clInstance.context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, outputBufferSize, NULL, &err);
    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(clInstance.commandQueue, inputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, inputBufferSize, x0, 0, NULL, NULL);

    assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);

    // cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(clInstance.program, "_ZNU3AS48impl_ERKILi4E7f_ODE_1E5solveEPU3AS2fPU3AS4fffPU3AS4Kf", &err);
    // assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_uint num_kernels_ret = 0;
    err = clCreateKernelsInProgram(clInstance.program, 0, NULL, &num_kernels_ret);


    err = clCreateKernelsInProgram(clInstance.program, num_kernels_ret, &kernel, NULL);
```

Why isn't my kernel function `__kernel void compute(.)` recognized by openCL?

Edit:
Replacing

```
err = clCreateKernelsInProgram(clInstance.program, 0, NULL, &num_kernels_ret);


err = clCreateKernelsInProgram(clInstance.program, num_kernels_ret, &kernel, NULL);
```

with

`cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(clInstance.program, "compute", &err);`

results in error code `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME`

The Khronos registry mentions [cl_khr_spir](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_spir.html) which is used to add support for creating OpenCL program objects from SPIRV. Is this necessary when compiling from clang with `-clc-std=c++2021`?

Comment: `clBuildProgram` has more possible return values than `CL_SUCCESS` or `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`. Can you change the logic to get the build log for any non-`CL_SUCCESS` error code, and post it here?

Comment: The return value for `clBuildProgram` is in this case `CL_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be unrelated to the creation of the kernel, and rather related to issues with an early termination of file reading.

With `ERK.spv` loaded properly OpenCL has no issues with kernel creation, using both

```
err = clCreateKernelsInProgram(clInstance.program, 0, NULL, &num_kernels_ret);


err = clCreateKernelsInProgram(clInstance.program, num_kernels_ret, &kernel, NULL);
```

and

```
cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(clInstance.program, "compute", &err);
```